# Use builtin python function when imported a function of same name

Tags: python, pyspark

I have imports as the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```

Within these there is a filter function in PySpark. How do I use the python filter function instead. Is the only way to import from PySpark the functions I require?

Comment: starred imports: `from pyspark.sql.functions import *` are discouraged for *precisely this reason*. Just don't use it

Comment: The best practice is to import external functions with an alias

Answer (score 4):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as pyr
```

then just use `pyr.filter()` to use pyspark filter and `filter()` to use python builtin

In general it's better to not use '' `from .. import *` '' because you're losing informations about which library you're using function from, making your code less clear even thought smaller